# StreamingTemplateEngine exception MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy

How to avoid occurrence MissingPropertyException at absence of parameters from a template in Map and to replace not found values by null?

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine
import groovy.text.Template

class Test {

    private static Writable binding(Map map, String string) {
        Template template = new StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(string)
        return template.make(map)
    }

    static void main(String... args) {
        def template = "\${test1} \${test2}"
        def map = ["test1": "test1"]
        print binding(map, template)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide an reproducible example.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber you are right, I added an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no configuration option to suppress this exception, however you can extend a map you pass to the template and change its behavior a bit. Consider following example:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine
import groovy.text.Template

def string = '''
Dear <% out.print firstname %> ${lastname},

We <% if (accepted) out.print 'are pleased' else out.print 'regret' %> 
to inform you that your paper entitled
'$title' was ${ accepted ? 'accepted' : 'rejected' }.

The conference committee.
'''

def map = [
    firstname: 'test',
    lastname: 'test',
    accepted: true
]

Template template = new StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(string)
println template.make(map)
```

It fails with the following exception:

```
Caught: groovy.text.TemplateExecutionException: Template execution error at line 4:
         3:     We <% if (accepted) out.print 'are pleased' else out.print 'regret' %>     to inform you that your paper entitled
     --> 4:     '$title' was ${ accepted ? 'accepted' : 'rejected' }.
         5:     

groovy.text.TemplateExecutionException: Template execution error at line 4:
         3:     We <% if (accepted) out.print 'are pleased' else out.print 'regret' %>     to inform you that your paper entitled
     --> 4:     '$title' was ${ accepted ? 'accepted' : 'rejected' }.
         5:     

    at test.run(test.groovy:21)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: title for class: groovy.tmp.templates.StreamingTemplateScript1
    ... 1 more
```

It fails because we have defined 3 from 4 template variables (variable `title` is missing).

#### Solution: create wrapper for a `Map`

Let's fix it. We will do it by overriding map method `containsKey(Object key)` in a way that it always returns `true` (this method is used by the template engine and if it returns `false`, template engine throws an exception). We will create a wrapper class that encapsulates a map and delegates invocation of non existing methods to this wrapped class. We will call this class `Bindings`.

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine
import groovy.text.Template

class Bindings {
    @Delegate private final Map map

    Bindings(Map map) {
        this.map = map
    }

    boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return true
    }
}

def string = '''
Dear <% out.print firstname %> ${lastname},

We <% if (accepted) out.print 'are pleased' else out.print 'regret' %> 
to inform you that your paper entitled
'$title' was ${ accepted ? 'accepted' : 'rejected' }.

The conference committee.
'''

def map = [
    firstname: 'test',
    lastname: 'test',
    accepted: true
]

Template template = new StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(string)
println template.make(new Bindings(map))
```

Output:

```
Dear test test,

We are pleased 
to inform you that your paper entitled
'null' was accepted.

The conference committee.
```

There is no `MissingPropertyException` thrown anymore. However, as you can see, `null` is printed as `null` inside the String. If you would like to print an empty string instead, you can add `Object get(Object key)` method to `Bindings` and override its default behavior:

```
class Bindings {
    @Delegate private final Map map

    Bindings(Map map) {
        this.map = map
    }

    boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return true
    }

    Object get(Object key) {
        return map.getOrDefault(key, '')
    }
}
```

If you do so, you will see the output similar to:

```
Dear test test,

We are pleased 
to inform you that your paper entitled
'' was accepted.

The conference committee.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, wrapper for a Map helped me

Comment: Wow it helps and saves me big time, thanks

Comment: Is there a way to keep the default value feature like ${myAbsentKey ?: 'defaultValue'} ? Because with this solution always sets null if the key is not present :'(

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can just use the groovy [Map.withDefault](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#withDefault(groovy.lang.Closure)) method:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine
import groovy.text.Template

def string = '''
Dear <% out.print firstname %> ${lastname},

We <% if (accepted) out.print 'are pleased' else out.print 'regret' %> 
to inform you that your paper entitled
'$title' was ${ accepted ? 'accepted' : 'rejected' }.

The conference committee.
'''

def map = [
    firstname: 'test',
    lastname: 'test',
    accepted: true
].withDefault { "<not found>" }

Template template = new StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(string)
println template.make(map)
```

where the only change to the OPs code is the `withDefault` clause. Executing the above prints:

```
~> groovy test.groovy

Dear test test,

We are pleased
to inform you that your paper entitled
'<not found>' was accepted.

The conference committee.
```

As a side note, I wrote the [streaming template engine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/StreamingTemplateEngine.html) as a contribution and a response to the limitations of the other template engines at the time a few years back. Glad to see it being used!

Though in hindsight it's far from perfect. Writing another one with a better internal approach has been on my list for aeons.