# StreamingTemplateEngine in Jenkins Pipeline vs. in plain groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In a Jenkins Pipeline we want to create a config File with variable content and so we use StreamingTemplateEngine. 
Now we have to build a Config File with optional lines depending on the variable map. This example was our first try (during development / testing first written in plain groovy):

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

def vars=[
    "KEY2": "VAL2",
]

templateText='''
FIXKEY=FIXVAL
<%
if(KEY1) out.print "KEY1="+KEY1+"\\n";
if(KEY2) out.print "KEY2="+KEY2+"\\n";
%>
'''

def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
def template=engine.createTemplate(templateText)
configContent = template.make(vars).toString()
println "CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:"
println configContent;
```

So as "KEY1" does not exist in the map we wanted the resulting config String to be:

```
FIXKEY=FIXVAL
KEY2=VAL2
```

But we got this exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" groovy.text.TemplateExecutionException: Template execution error at line 4:
         3: <%
     --> 4: if(KEY1) out.print "KEY1="+KEY1+"\n";
         5: if(KEY2) out.print "KEY2="+KEY2+"\n";

    at main.run(main.groovy:34)
    at main.main(main.groovy)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: KEY1 for class: groovy.tmp.templates.StreamingTemplateScript1
```

So we learned, that every variable used in the template has to be defined in the map, as this code works:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

def vars=[
    "KEY1": "VAL1",
    "KEY2": "VAL2",
]

templateText='''
FIXKEY=FIXVAL
<%
if(KEY1) out.print "KEY1="+KEY1+"\\n";
if(KEY2) out.print "KEY2="+KEY2+"\\n";
%>
'''

def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
def template=engine.createTemplate(templateText)
configContent = template.make(vars).toString()
println "CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:"
println configContent;
```

But results in:

```
FIXKEY=FIXVAL
KEY1=VAL1
KEY2=VAL2
```

Now we could define "KEY2":false in the map, but with a huge amount of vars this would be quite much more work as just to define the neccessary vars and leaving the not needed vars completely out.

After a bit of searching we found this:

[StreamingTemplateEngine exception MissingPropertyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335047/streamingtemplateengine-exception-missingpropertyexception)

We tried the second solution mentioned in this thread:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

def vars=[
    "KEY2": "VAL2",
].withDefault { false }

templateText='''
FIXKEY=FIXVAL
<%
if(KEY1) out.print "KEY1="+KEY1+"\\n";
if(KEY2) out.print "KEY2="+KEY2+"\\n";
%>
'''

def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
def template=engine.createTemplate(templateText)
configContent = template.make(vars).toString()
println "CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:"
println configContent;
```

And that works as expected, the resulting config content is:

```
FIXKEY=FIXVAL
KEY2=VAL2
```

Perfect, we thought, so now we want to use this snippet in a Jenkins Pipeline, but Jenkins behaves somehow different using this test stage code:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

[...]

           stage('test') {
                def vars=[
                    "KEY2": "VAL2",
                ].withDefault { false }

                templateText='''
    FIXKEY=FIXVAL
    <%
    if(KEY1) out.print "KEY1="+KEY1+"\\n";
    if(KEY2) out.print "KEY2="+KEY2+"\\n";
    %>
    '''
                def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
                def template=engine.createTemplate(templateText)
                configContent = template.make(vars).toString()
                println "CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:"
                println configContent;
            }
```

But the result in Jenkins is this:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
15:07:10  CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:
[Pipeline] echo
15:07:10  false
[Pipeline] }
```

Notice the single "false" ??!!

When "completing" the map like this:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

[...]

           stage('test') {
                def vars=[
                    "KEY1": "VAL1",
                    "KEY2": "VAL2",
                ].withDefault { false }

                templateText='''
    FIXKEY=FIXVAL
    <%
    if(KEY1) out.print "KEY1="+KEY1+"\\n";
    if(KEY2) out.print "KEY2="+KEY2+"\\n";
    %>
    '''
                def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
                def template=engine.createTemplate(templateText)
                configContent = template.make(vars).toString()
                println "CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:"
                println configContent;
            }
```

the content String is as expected:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
15:09:06  CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:
[Pipeline] echo
15:09:06  
15:09:06  FIXKEY=FIXVAL
15:09:06  KEY1=VAL1
15:09:06  KEY2=VAL2
15:09:06  
15:09:06  
[Pipeline] }
```

So why does Jenkins Pipeline Groovy behave different with the same Code Snippet than "Plain" Groovy?

Or is there even a completely different approach to solve the request "variable lines based on var - existence in the map"?

Thx for any hint!
T0mcat

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the problem you face is the fact that the following expression:

```
def vars=[
    "KEY1": "VAL1",
    "KEY2": "VAL2",
].withDefault { false }
```

returns an instance of [`MapWithDefault<K,V>`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovy/lang/MapWithDefault.java#L30) class. This object generates an issue inside the Jenkins pipeline because the pipeline uses Groovy CPS library for continuous-passing style transformation. This mode comes with some limitations. For instance, it requires that all objects you use in the pipeline have to be `Serializable`.

> Pipeline scripts may mark designated methods with the annotation `@NonCPS`. These are then compiled normally (except for sandbox security checks), and so behave much like “binary” methods from the Java Platform, Groovy runtime, or Jenkins core or plugin code. `@NonCPS` methods may safely use non-`Serializable` objects as local variables, though they should not accept nonserializable parameters or return or store nonserializable values. You may not call regular (CPS-transformed) methods, or Pipeline steps, from a `@NonCPS` method, so they are best used for performing some calculations before passing a summary back to the main script. Note in particular that `@Overrides` of methods defined in binary classes, such as Object.toString(), should in general be marked `@NonCPS` since it will commonly be binary code calling them.
>
> Source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin#technical-design

In the case of Groovy classes, this requirement is satisfied out-of-the-box, because every Groovy class implicitly implements `Serializable` interface. In the case of Java classes, this interface has to be implemented explicitly. As you can see this `MapWithDefault<K,V>` class is a Java class and it does not implement `Serializable` interface.

### Solution 1: extract the logic to the `@NonCPS` method

Consider the following example:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

node {

   stage('test') {
        def vars=[
            "KEY2": "VAL2",
        ]

        String templateText='''
        FIXKEY=FIXVAL
        <%
        if(KEY1) out.print "KEY1="+KEY1+"\\n";
        if(KEY2) out.print "KEY2="+KEY2+"\\n";
        %>
    '''

        configContent = parseAsConfigString(templateText, vars)
        println "CONTENT FROM TEMPLATE IS:"
        println configContent;
    }
}

@NonCPS
def parseAsConfigString(String templateText, Map vars) {
    def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
    def template=engine.createTemplate(templateText)
    return template.make(vars.withDefault { false }).toString()
}
```

In this case, a method `parseAsConfigString` handles the generation of a config string. Keep in mind that it accepts a normal hash map (which is serializable) and it transforms it to the `MapWithDefault` inside the `@NonCPS` method, so non-serializable object is not used outside the context of the `@NonCPS` method. The `StreamingTemplateEngine` object is also used inside the method, because this class does not implement `Serializable` interface, so it could cause some weird problems as well.

### Solution 2: use `ConfigObject` instead

Even though the solution with template engine may work for you, I would suggest using `ConfigObject` instead. This class was designed for representing configuration objects and it has a few useful methods. You can create an instance of `ConfigObject` from any map, and then you can call `prettyPrint()` method to generate a String representation of a configuration. Consider the following example:

```
node {
   stage('test') {
       def map = [
                KEYVAL1: "VAL2",
                FIXKEY: "FIXVAL"
        ]

        def config = new ConfigObject()
        config.putAll(map)

        println config.prettyPrint()
   }
}
```

The output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
KEYVAL1='VAL2'
FIXKEY='FIXVAL'

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
```

The main difference between both approaches is that strings in the pretty print of a `ConfigObject` are wrapped with single quotes, which is something I would actually expect. In this approach all you have to do is to prepare a proper map that stores configuration options and transforming it to `ConfigObject` allows you to print it in the desired form.